# Show only filtered layers in qgs Composer legend - PyQgis

Tags: python, plugins, legend, qgis, legend-properties

I am developing custom Qgis plugin. I want to export the map canvas in the form of an image along with the legend. The code for the legend is:

```
legend = QgsComposerLegend(c)
legend.model().setLayerSet(mapRenderer.layerSet())
c.addItem(legend)
```

The problem is that it adds all the layers in the map legend, whereas I only want to include the layer which are visible in map extent, in the map legend. I have also tried:

```
legend.setLegendFilterByMapEnabled(True)
```

But this does not seem to work. Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

i have solved this problem by splitting the map plot and the legend plot.
I mean ; After creating and saving a plot for the map plot, i created another mapcanvas-renderer for the legend plot and this time i removed unwanted layers by using removeMapLayer method.Then save the legend plot as well.

```
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().removeMapLayer(the_unwanted_layer)
```

i hope this helps